# Small scope/huge frustration mystery: buggy array behavior in php

Tags: php, arrays

So crazy! I have a bug that's 100% reproducible, it happens in only a few lines of code, yet I cannot for the life of me determine what the problem is.

My project is a workout maker, and the mystery involves two functions:

- get_pairings: It makes a set of $together_pairs (easy) and $mixed_pairs (annoying), and combines them into $all_pairs, used to make the workout.
- make_mixed_pairs: this has different logic depending on whether it's a partner vs solo workout.  Both cases return a set of $mixed_pairs (in the same exact format), called by the function above.

**The symptoms/clues:**

1. The case of the solo workout is fine, $all_pairs will only contain $mixed_pairs (because as it's defined, $together_pairs are only for partner workouts)
2. In the case of the a partner workout, when I combine the two sets in get_pairings(), $all_pairs only successfully gets the first set I give it! (If I swap those lines at step 2 and add $together_pairs first, $all_pairs contains only those.   If I do $mixed_pairs first, $all_pairs contains only that).
3. Then if I uncomment that second-to-last line in make_mixed_pairs() just for troubleshooting to see what happens, then $all_pairs does successfully include exercises from both sets!

That suggests the problem is something I'm doing wrong in making the arrays in make_mixed_pairs(), but I confirmed that the resulting format is identical in both cases.

Anyone see what else I could be missing? I've been narrowing down this bug for 4 hours so far- I can't make it any smaller, and I can't see what's wrong :(

**Update**: I updated the for loop in make_mixed_pairs() to stop at $mixed_pair_count - 1 (instead of just $mixed_pair_count), and now I sometimes get one single 'together_pair' mixed in the $all_pairs results; the same damn one each time, weirdly.  Though it's not 'fixed', because again when I change the order that I add the two sets in get_pairings, when I add $together_pairs first, then $all_pairs is ENTIRELY those- it's so strange...

Here are the functions: first get_pairings (relevant part is right before and after step 2):

```
/**
* Used in make_workout.php: take the user's available resources, and return valid exercises
*/
function get_pairings($exercises, $count, $outdoor_partner_workout)      
{
// 1. Prep our variables, and put exercises into the appropriate buckets
    $mixed_exercises = array();

    $together_pairs = array();
    $mixed_pairs = array();
    $all_pairs = array();
    $selected_pairs = array();

    // Sort the valid exercises: self_pairing exercises go as they are, with extra
    // array for consistent formatting. Mixed ones go into $mixed_exercises array 
    // for more specialized pairing in make_mixed_pairs

    foreach($exercises as $exercise)
    {
        if ($exercise['self_pairing'])
        {
            $pair = array($exercise);
            array_push($together_pairs, [$pair]); 
        }
        else 
            {
                $this_exercise = array($exercise);
                array_push($mixed_exercises, $this_exercise); 
            }
    }

    // Now get the mixed_pairs 
    $mixed_pairs = make_mixed_pairs($mixed_exercises, $outdoor_partner_workout);  

// 2. combine together into one set, and select random pairs for the workout

    // Add both sets to the array of all pairs (to pick from afterward)

    $all_pairs += $mixed_pairs;
    $all_pairs += $together_pairs;

    // Now let's choose at random our desired # of pairs, and save them in $selected_pairs
    $pairing_keys = array_rand($all_pairs, $count);

    foreach($pairing_keys as $key)
    {
        array_push($selected_pairs, $all_pairs[$key]);
    }    

    // Finally, shuffle it so we don't always see the self-pairs first
    shuffle($selected_pairs);    

    return $selected_pairs;
}
```

And the other one- make_mixed_pairs: there are two cases, the first is complicated (and shows the bug) and the second is simple (and works):

```
/**
* Used by get_pairings: in case of a partner workout that has open space (where 
* one person can travel to a point while the other does an exercise til they return)
* we'll pair exercises in a special way.  (If not, fine to grab random pairs)
*/    
function make_mixed_pairs($mixed_exercises, $outdoor_partner_workout)      
{
    $mixed_pairs = array();

    // When it's an outdoor partner workout, we want to pair travelling with stationary
    // put them into arrays and then we'll make pairs using one from each
    if ($outdoor_partner_workout)
    {
        $mixed_travelling = array();
        $mixed_stationary = array();        

        foreach($mixed_exercises as $exercise)
        {
            if ($exercise[0]['travelling'])
            {
                array_push($mixed_travelling, $exercise);
            }
            else
            {
                array_push($mixed_stationary, $exercise);
            }
        }

        shuffle($mixed_travelling);
        shuffle($mixed_stationary);

        // determine the smaller set, and pair exercises that many times
        $mixed_pair_count = min(count($mixed_travelling), count($mixed_stationary));

        for ($i=0; $i < $mixed_pair_count; $i++)
        {
            $this_pair = array($mixed_travelling[$i], $mixed_stationary[$i]);

            array_push($mixed_pairs, $this_pair);  // problem is adding them here- we get only self_pairs
        }

    }    

    // Otherwise we can just grab pairs from mixed_exercises
    else 
        {
            // shuffle the array so it's in random order, then chunk it into pairs
            shuffle($mixed_exercises);
            $mixed_pairs = array_chunk($mixed_exercises, 2);
        }
    // $mixed_pairs = array_chunk($mixed_exercises, 2);  // when I replace it with this, it works

    return $mixed_pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh for Pete's sake: I mentioned this to a friend, who told me that union is flukey in php, and that I should use array_merge instead.

I replaced these lines:

```
$all_pairs += $together_pairs;
$all_pairs += $mixed_pairs;
```

with this:

```
$all_pairs = array_merge($together_pairs, $mixed_pairs);
```

And now it all works